# How to access Zoom meeting information using Python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, zoom-sdk

I'm new to using Zoom API and Python. I'm planning to get all Zoom meeting information. I've created an OAuth app to authenticate and authorize users to make requests. I can't use JWT app because of some confidential issues. Just want to learn how to start, like how to get an access token and get basic zoom information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can get started here and in case you need any tutorial google process of using python with oauth

```
https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32151744)